# Pass loop value along with a string

Tags: arrays, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to move among the sheets within the same workbook, my sheet names are like 'Order 1', 'Order 2', 'Order 3'........so on. I want to take the value from loop along with 'Order' string like 'Order [i]' and want to paste some formula that also takes some value from the loop like ={Link!B[[i]+2]}

I tried with this following code but can't be succeeded.

```
function Order() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Order [i]'));
    spreadsheet.getRange('B3').activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('={Link!B[[i]+2]}');;
  }  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify `'Order [i]'`, your script looks for a sheet called "Order [i]". Instead, you should write `'Order ' + i`.

Similarly, `'={Link!B[[i]+2]}'` will return "={Link!B[[i]+2]}", just as you wrote it. Instead, write `'={Link!B' + (i+2) + '}'`.

Also, you don't need the `.activate()` or `.setActiveSheet()` calls. You can simply get the range and then immediately set the value. You're getting the sheet already with the `.getSheetByName()` method. In fact, you link all of it together.

```
function Order() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Order ' + i)
      .getRange('B3')
      .setValue('={Link!B' + (i+2) + '}');
  }  
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I have changed something from your code and it works

Comment: @MubashirAli Great. What did you change?

Comment: function Order() {
  for (var i=1;i<=10;i++){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Order '+i), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('={Link1!B' + (i+2) + '}');
  }
};

Comment: @MubashirAli Thanks for sharing it. As I mentioned, you don't need those activation calls, but as long as it work it's fine :) Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

The string `'Order [i]'` will always just be `'Order [i]'`, as everything is wrapped in quotes so the computer is interpreting it literally. You want to use something like `'Order ' + i`, which will evaluate what `i` is and then append it to `'Order'`.

In the second example, you might want something like `'={Link!' + B[i+2] + '}'`

Comment: Thanks, I have made it. People from stack overflow community are great. I have also posted this question on the Google community and have nothing from there for 2 days.